# Allow Contributors to Upload Files

Tags: users, user-roles

I would like to allow contributors to upload a file. So I use this recommended plugin `WP Role Editor` After activated, I go to the plugin from `User > User Role Editor` and then select contributor in the selection dropdown. After that I put a check on `upload_files` and hit update. Then, I login with contributor account to test uploading a file. Great, I see the media upload button but when I click to upload a file, I get this error:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this post

I posted a question about this in their support forums but the plugin author hasn't given a solution.

Now, I tried the code below that I've found in Google. However, it doesn't show the upload media button at all.

```
// Let Contributor Role to Upload Media
if( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) && ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) )
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads' );
    function allow_contributor_uploads() {
        $contributor = get_role( 'contributor' );
        $contributor->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
    }
```

So, what else can I do to get this done? Why doesn't WordPress allow Contributor role to upload a files? According to the theme I use, I have to set this role by default for register users if I want users to submit a post with approval.

Comment: Roles have dependencies, so `upload_files` likely isn't enough, without seeing the full list of capabilities a contributor has and how yours differs from a normal contributor I don't know how this question can be answered easily. Do contributors have the `edit_posts` capability?

Comment: Sure, you can see the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/41bbphu1zm6b3y1/Screenshot%202018-02-20%2023.33.12.png?dl=0

Comment: And you've checked `upload_files`? Have you contacted support for the WP Role Editor plugin?

Comment: It seems that you didn't read my details at all.

Comment: I did read your details, I see that your screenshot doesn't show the upload_files checkbox so I can't see if you've enabled it in the plugin. I also saw your code, but I'm trying to ascertain if your code is even necessary, and if it's being overridden by the WP Roles Editor plugin

Comment: I've checked that as mentioned in the details. But I didn't capture it due to the fact that I have to scroll down. If I scroll down, the thing doesn't appear in one capture due to the screen size of my laptop. And you ask me about "edit_posts".  So I took only that point of screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to make subscribers upload files and it works successfully..
I think you must add true in the last line.

```
if ( current_user_can('subscriber') && !current_user_can('upload_files') ) {

    add_action('init', 'allow_subscriber_uploads');

    function allow_subscriber_uploads() {
      $new_role = get_role('subscriber');
      $new_role->add_cap('upload_files', true);
     }
 }
```